# How delete a request id without the current user id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, request

With the new request id system request id are composed of 2 parts, the request id and the user id. The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/#deleting)
says you must delete the request id using the full id of the request but if the user has no accepted the application you can't have his id? Before when you accessed to the request you have a to field containing information about the user but now it's gone if the user haven't accepted the application?

So my question how access to the user id if he hasn't accepted the application? It clearly express that we need to delete the request but without the user id it can't be done).

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue in my own app. I've submitted a bug report since there doesn't seem to be any way of doing so (even though the Javascript SDK seems like it should work at first glance) https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/239476836116522